# What did Italian telegraph style look like?

Tags: writing

What the title says.

In English, they would spell out the words "stop", "comma", "colon" and "semicolon" in telegrams, when the punctuation was crucial for the meaning.

In Russian, one would use the tokens *тчк, зпт* etc., which are Russian words *точка* "full stop", *запятая* "comma" etc. with the vowels omitted. Russian also has cases, so the prepositions which were not crucial for understanding were often omitted as well

How did it work in Italian? What were the tokens, if any, for "stop", "comma" etc? Did they have any means to convey vowel accents and did they do that on a regular basis? Did they omit articles, copulas and other words not crucial for the meaning?

I'm looking for a way to translate the telegram "UNABLE OBTAIN BIDET STOP SUGGEST HANDSTAND IN SHOWER". It was sent by the filmmaker Billy Wilder to his wife, who had asked him to buy her a bidet in Paris.

My take is "NON RIESCO OTTENERE BIDET STOP SUGGERISCO VERTICALE IN DOCCIA", but I'm not sure about the punctuation and omitting articles and prepositions.

Comment: Let me add to the great answer by @BakerStreet, that, as a simple matter of linguistic register, I'd say something slight freer and less formal, such as “IMPOSSIBILE TROVARE BIDET” etc. “Ottenere” is perfectly good Italian, but less usual than is “to obtain” in English.

Comment: @DaG: "obtain" and "suggest" is not how you usually speak to your wife in English either, which is a part of the comedic effect. Is _ottenere_ high register in Italian?

Comment: @ Quassnoi *Ottenere* is not high register but more formal than *trovare* in this context. If you want a high/comedic register *ottenere* is good, also one could use *reperire*, more formal: *Non riesco reperire bidet* oppure anche, come suggerisce DaG  *Impossibile reperire bidet*.  These are choices of the translator, impossible to say what is the best choice.

Comment: *reperire* è più formale/burocratico, e accentua il tono alto-comico, nel contrasto tra il burocratico *reperire* e il prosaico *bidet*.

Comment: "handstand" could be read as "hand-stand" that's "maniglia"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't, as far as I know, rules for telegraph style in Italian.

We just use *stop* when necessary, I have never seen other words for punctuation as 'comma' or 'colon'.

We just omit all the words that are unnecessary for the comprehension of the message, such as articles, propositions, or verbs such as 'ho', 'è '.

I think your translation is very good.

Comment: Do you know if they omitted the accents in vowels and if there were any means to transmit them at all?

Comment: I don't know exactly, I think no, accents are not omitted, because there could be confusion, for instance, between *e* and *è* the verb. I don't know if in a telegram there were letter with accent, I think that instead of the accent, if there aren't specifically letter with the accent, an apostrophe  can be used.  Now an apostrophe instead of an accent is a mistake, but once it was quite normal, and in a telegram can be used, telegraph style is an informal language.

Comment: could you please add it to the answer? thanks!

Comment: Accents weren't used in Italian telegrams, I believe, and I'm not sure Morse code included them. I vaguely remember the use of “ET” and “EST” to disambiguate “e/è”.

Comment: @DaG: for what it's worth, the Morse code was only use for the telegraph for a relatively short time (~1850s through 1880s), it was neither the first nor the last. The newer Baudot code did have a separate code point for `é` (and only that). It looks like it was mostly a French thing, though. But the piece about _et / est_ is really interesting. Could you please make it into an answer? Thank you!

Comment: @ Quassnoi The problem is that these are just my suppositions, I don't remember how accents were treated in telegrams, after DaG remembered the use of EST and ET I also have a memory of it.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of “non riesco” I suggest “impossibile”; it saves a word (I believe you paid telegrams by number of words) plus it renders the somewhat dramatic tone associated with telegrams in Italian.
Also, I suggest “suggerisco *fare* verticale in doccia”, as in Italian the expression “fare la verticale” is used, while simply “verticale” may not be as clear.

Comment: Hai ragione, ci ho messo una mezz'oretta a capire che voleva dire 'verticale in doccia'.

Comment: Almeno nell'Unione Sovietica, si pagavano ogni dieci lettere di una parola, "non riesco" e "impossibile" sarebbero costate lo stesso. Ma il problema più grande è che _unable_ è personale: _(I am) unable (to)_, mentre "impossibile" no. C'e qualche parola personale sola che significhi lo stesso di "non riesco"?

Comment: The anecdote is _also_ quoted with “impossible” rather than “unable”: https://www.google.it/books/edition/The_Little_Brown_Book_of_Anecdotes/2vH3SeQFcBIC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22obtain+bidet%22&pg=PT866&printsec=frontcover

Comment: Ciò che intendevo dire è anche che in Italiano per i telegrammi effettivamente si adotta uno stile impersonale, con la conseguenza di sembrare altisonanti, un po’ eccessivi e a volte involontariamente buffi. Una pubblicità di molti anni fa di un noto ristorante, posta sotto forma di telegramma inviato da un ipotetico cliente recitava: “subita dittatura gastronomica STOP la vita è bella STOP saluti”. Cioè “subita”, non “subisco”